# Proof verification: Is $(\mathbb{R}[x], ||\cdot||_q)$ a normed linear space?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, polynomials, proof-verification, normed-spaces

We set 
$$\mathbb{R}[x] := \{ \alpha = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0 :  \ a_i \in \mathbb{R} \ \ \  \forall i = 1,2\ldots , n\}.$$
for some non-negative integer $n$. It is well-known that $\mathbb{R}[x]$ becomes a vector space with addition and multiplication defined as follows.

---

(i) If $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ with $\alpha = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$ and $\beta = b_nx^n + \cdots + b_1x + b_0$, then
$$\alpha + \beta = (a_n+b_n)x^n + \cdots + (a_1+b_1)x + (a_0+ b_0) \in \mathbb{R}[x] .$$
(ii) If $\alpha = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0 \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then 
$$c \alpha = a_ncx^n + \cdots + a_1cx + a_0c \in \mathbb{R}[x].$$

---

For each $\alpha = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0 \in \mathbb{R}[x]$, we define
$$deg(\alpha) = \begin{cases}
n & \text{ if } a_n \neq 0 \\ 
-\infty & \text{ if } \alpha = 0 
\end{cases}.$$
Fix $q >1$. Define the map $||\cdot||_q:\mathbb{R}[x] \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ by
$$||\alpha||_q = q^{deg(\alpha)}.$$
The question is if $||\cdot||_q$ is a norm in $\mathbb{R}[x]$?

(a) $||\alpha||_q \geq 0$.

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}[x],$ so $\alpha = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $a_n \neq 0$. We then have:
$$||\alpha||_q = q^{deg(\alpha)} = q^n,$$
but $q > 1$, so $q^n > 0$ and thus $||\alpha||_q \geq 0$. In particular, if the leading coefficient is zero, then $q^{deg(\alpha)} > 0$, because $q > 1$. Hence (a) is satisfied.

(b) $||\alpha||_q = 0 \Leftrightarrow \alpha = 0$.

"$\Rightarrow$"

Suppose $||\alpha||_q = 0$, we then have $q^{deg(\alpha)} = 0$. Since $q > 1$, the only possible way that $q^{deg(\alpha)} = 0$ is that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{q}\right)^n = 0,$$
this implies that $q^{-\infty} = 0$. Then $deg(\alpha) = -\infty$ which gives $\alpha = 0$.

"$\Leftarrow$"

Assume that $\alpha = 0$, then $deg(\alpha) = -\infty$ and 
$$||\alpha||_q = q^{deg(\alpha)} = q^{-\infty} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{q}\right)^n = 0,$$
hence (b) is also satisfied.

(c) $||\alpha + \beta||_q \leq ||\alpha||_q + ||\beta||_q$.

Without loss of generality, we suppose that $$\alpha = a_nx^n + \cdots + a_1x + a_0$$ and $$\beta = b_mx^m + \cdots + b_1x + b_0,$$ where $m \leq n$. If $m = n$, then $\beta = b_nx^n + \cdots + b_1x + b_0$ and 
$$\alpha + \beta = (a_n+b_n)x^n + \cdots + (a_1+b_1)x + (a_0+ b_0),$$
and 
$$||\alpha + \beta||_q = q^{\deg(\alpha + \beta)} = q^{\deg(\alpha)} = q^{\deg( \beta)}.$$
Otherwise, set $m < n$. We then have $\beta = b_mx^m + \cdots + b_1x + b_0$, and 
$$\alpha + \beta = a_nx^n + \cdots + (a_m + b_m)x^m + \cdots + (a_1+b_1)x + (a_0+ b_0).$$
We thus have
$$||\alpha + \beta||_q = q^{\deg(\alpha + \beta)} = q^{\deg(\alpha)}.$$
In a more general case, we have the inequality
$$||\alpha + \beta||_q \leq \max\{||\alpha||_q, ||\beta||_q\}.$$
But does the triangle inequality holds in this case? We are given $q >1$ and in particular $q^k > 1$ for any $k \geq 1$. If $m = n$, we get 
$$||\alpha + \beta||_q = q^{\deg(\alpha + \beta)} = q^{\deg(\alpha)} < q^{\deg(\alpha)} + q^{\deg(\beta)} = ||\alpha||_q + ||\beta||_q.$$
Otherwise, we have 
$$||\alpha + \beta||_q \leq \max\{||\alpha||_q, ||\beta||_q\}.$$ 
We consider two cases, if $\max\{||\alpha||_q, ||\beta||_q\} = ||\alpha||_q$, then 
$$\max\{||\alpha||_q, ||\beta||_q\} \leq ||\alpha||_q + ||\beta||_q.$$
If $\max\{||\alpha||_q, ||\beta||_q\} = ||\beta||_q$, then 
$$\max\{||\alpha||_q, ||\beta||_q\} \leq ||\beta||_q + ||\alpha||_q.$$
Does this implies that the inequality
$$||\alpha + \beta||_q \leq ||\alpha||_q + ||\beta||_q,$$
holds?

(d) Finally, for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ ,we set
$$c \alpha = a_ncx^n + \cdots + a_1cx + a_0c \in \mathbb{R}[x].$$
Now,
$$||c \alpha||_q = q^{deg(c\alpha)} = q^{deg(\alpha)},$$
because $c$ is a scalar. Therefore
$$||c \alpha||_q = ||\alpha||_q \neq |c| ||\alpha||_q,$$
unless $c = 1$. Thus the **Positive Homogeneity** property is not satisfied. Hence  $(\mathbb{R}[x], ||\cdot||_q)$ is not  a normed linear space.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct,but in d), what happens if $c=0$?. The most delicate part was c), but you do it very well.

**Addendum:** there is a more general theory about this norm (maybe you already know). See a little piece [$p$-adic numbers](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2011/REUPapers/Herwig.pdf).

Comment: If $c = 0$, then $c\alpha = 0$ and by part (b), we have $||c \alpha||_q = ||0||_q = 0$? I have heard a bit about $p-$adic numbers, but my knowledge about them is almost non-existent. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Exactly. Then $||c \alpha||_q = ||\alpha||_q \neq |c| ||\alpha||_q,$ unless $c\neq 1$ or $c\neq 0$.